# extract substring until first digit

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep

I have the following string:

`test1234a` or `test1234` for example and I want to extract only `test` from that string.

I tried the follwing

```
echo "Test12h" | sed -e 's/[0-9]\*$//' but is not working.
```

Is there any possibility to extract the substring until first digit?

Please let me know what I miss.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/\([^0-9]*\).*/\1/' Input_file
```

OR

```
sed 's/[0-9][0-9a-zA-Z]*//' Input_file
```

Answer (score 7):

The proper tool for extracting substrings matching a regexp from a command's output is `grep`. Like,

```
echo "Test12h" | grep -o '^[^[:digit:]]*'
```

will output `Test`.

If `Test12h` is in a variable, you don't even need external utilities; parameter expansions can easily handle that, e.g:

```
var='Test12h'
echo "${var%%[[:digit:]]*}"
```

Answer (score 4):

If the source happens to reside in a variable you can use [parameter substitution](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html), eg:

```
$ for test in test1234a test1234 Test12h
do
    echo "${test} => ${test//[0-9]*/}"
done
test1234a => test
test1234 => test
Test12h => Test
```

Where the general format is: `${var//Pattern/Replacement}`; in the above:

- `var` == test
- `Patter`n == `[0-9]*` (first occurrence of a digit and then everything that follows
- `Replacement` == '' (nothing, empty string)

So we end up stripping off everything after the first occurrence of a number.

Comment: Just a little nitpick, `${test/[0-9]*}` should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

You made a small error in your try:

```
echo "Test12h" | sed -e 's/[0-9].*$//'    # will output Test
```

The `\*` expects a real `*` in the input:

```
echo "Test1*" | sed -e 's/[0-9]\*$//'     # will output Test
```

The `.*` matches any number of any characters.